# Adding custom frameworks to Xcode frameworks list?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have made a framework in Xcode. Each time I want to add it to another project, I  need to look for it in its folder. Is there a way to add it to the frameworks list (like all the Apple frameworks) so that it's easier to add to a project?

Thanks.

Comment: As in I need to do "Add Other..."